# Remove ugly space before \bigvee

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

For example, I have the next code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \section{Секція 1}
    {\sffamily Диз'юктивне прозкладання булевої функція за \(k\) змінними:}
    \begin{gather}
        f(x_1,\ldots,x_k,x_{k+1},\ldots,x_n) =\bigvee_{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_n)}x_1^{\sigma_1}\land x_2^{\sigma_2}\land \ldots \land x_k^{\sigma_k}\land f(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_k, x_{k-1},\ldots,x_n)
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

It produces
[image]
But I wold like to get rid of space before (and maybe after) `\bigvee` permanently.
I do know about `\hspace{}` but I would have to write that damn `\hspace{\bigveespace}` or some command every time I use `\bigvee`, so yes, that isn't what I want to do.

How could I do it?

Comment: The "ugly" space is of course because of the long limit. There are some methods for this mentioned in the manual for the `mathtools` package.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `\ldots` between the `\land` terms -- use `\cdots` instead. Better still, use `\dots` throughout and let LaTeX decide when to use `\ldots` and when to use `\cdots`. (Hint: In fine math typography, employ `\cdots` when the typographic ellipsis occurs between binary or relational operators (such as `\land`) or between integral symbols, and employ `\ldots` when the ellipsis occurs between commas.)

Comment: @Mico Wow! It's so LaTex-like! I will not to think about what to use again(I am always stumbling about dots command), thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply two fixes, not just one fix:

- Mandatory: Introduce a line break in the formula. I suggest you place the line break after the `=` symbol while employing a `multline` environment.
- Optional: Eliminate the whitespace on either side of `\bigvee`. The [mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package, a superset of the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package, provides two methods for accomplishing this. Both methods are illustrated in the following example. For the case at hand, both methods happen to produce the same outcome; this is not true in general.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english, ukrainian]{babel}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{mathtools} % 'mathtools' is a superset of 'amsmath'

\begin{document}

%% (a) the \mathclap approach
\begin{multline}
 f(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)  \\
 =\bigvee_{\mathclap{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n)}}
   x_1^{\sigma_1}\land x_2^{\sigma_2}\land\dots\land x_k^{\sigma_k}\land 
   f(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_k, x_{k-1},\dots,x_n)
\end{multline}

%% (b) the \smashoperator approach
\begin{multline}
 f(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1},\dots,x_n)  \\
 =\smashoperator{\bigvee_{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_n)}}
   x_1^{\sigma_1}\land x_2^{\sigma_2}\land\dots\land x_k^{\sigma_k}\land 
   f(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_k, x_{k-1},\dots,x_n)
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just have been reading mathtools documentation and discovered that this package is very cool. Thank you for pointing out exactly what I needed!